# Check if all elements of an array alternate in direction

Tags: ruby

In Ruby, I need to check if all the elements of an array alternate in direction, i.e., if the predecessor and successor are greater or lesser than each element.

Giving the following arrays, the outcome must be as indicated

```
[1,3,2,4,3]  # => true
[3,2,4,3,5]  # => true
[1,2,3,1,3]. # => false 
[1,2,2,1,3]. # => false
```

I came out with the following code, which seems to work, but it's pretty or simple to understand.

```
array.each_cons(2)     # get subsequent couple of items
  .map {|a,b| b-a}.    # get the difference between first and second
  .map {|n| n <=> 0}   # get the sign (-1/+1)
  .each_cons(2)        # get couple of signs
  .map {|a,b| a+b}     # sum each couple
  .uniq == [0]         # return true if all the couple are 0
```

Any suggestion how to simplify the check?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
def alternate_direction?(arr)
  return true if arr.size < 3
  arr.each_cons(3) do |prev, curr, succ|
    return false unless (curr > prev && curr > succ) || (curr < prev && curr < succ)
  end
  true
end
```

Let us try to print now

```
puts alternate_direction?([1,3,2,4,3])  # => true
puts alternate_direction?([3,2,4,3,5])  # => true
puts alternate_direction?([1,2,3,1,3])  # => false
puts alternate_direction?([1,2,2,1,3])  # => false
```

Comment: You could utilize `arr.each_cons(3).all? { ... }`

Comment: For two-element arrays you might want to check if `arr[0] != arr[1]`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I ended up using `values.each_cons(3).all? { |p, c, s| (c > p && c > s) || (c < p && c < s) }`

Answer (score 2):

...only because @Rajagopalan has already taken `each_cons`,

```
def alt(arr)
  return true if arr.size < 3
  prev = arr[1]<=>arr[0]
  return false if prev.zero?
  (2..arr.size-1).all? do |i|
    prev = -prev
    (arr[i]<=>arr[i-1]) == prev
  end
end
```

```
[[1,3,2,4,3], [3,2,4,3,5], [1,2,3,1,3], [1,2,2,1,3], [2,2,1,4,3], [2,3], [2], []].
  map { |a| alt(a) }
  #=> [true, true, false, false, false, true, true, true]
```